# R list into a single data frame cell

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'd like to change a list into one cell of a data frame.

```
  list <- list(1,2,3,4,5)

View(list)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5
```

I'd like to transform this such that it looks like:

```
          x
1 1,2,3,4,5
```

The reason is because I have a loop that is storing result in a list for each iteration, but I only want one cell per iteration.

There are other columns where for each iteration, there is only one result. So saving that in a data frame is easy. But then for the metric with multiple results, I don't want multiple columns or rows.

So I will have two data frames that I can use `cbind` on such that my final data frame will look like:

```
          x y
1 1,2,3,4,5 a
2     5,4,3 b
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by `unlist` and `paste`, i.e.,

```
data.frame(x = paste(l1, collapse = ','))
#          x
#1 1,2,3,4,5
```

or simply (thanks @David)

```
data.frame(x = toString(list))
#              x
#1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

On a side note, avoid naming your lists 'list' as there is a function called `list` in R

Comment: Or just `toString(l1)` I guess. Or just `paste(l1, collapse = ',')` if you want the `paste` way

Comment: is toString much faster or just easier to write?

Comment: not sure. However, I doubt anyone would be extremely more efficient than the other.